# Creating a QgsFillSymbol from serialized QgsSymbolLayers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, serialize

I have a [`QgsFillSymbol`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsFillSymbol.html):

```
>>> symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '#ffa500'})
```

I can dump the symbol's [`QgsSymbolLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsSymbolLayer.html)s' properties in a dictionary structure:

```
>>> [symbol_layer.properties() for symbol_layer in symbol.symbolLayers()]
[
    {
        "border_width_map_unit_scale": "3x:0,0,0,0,0,0",
        "color": "255,165,0,255",
        "joinstyle": "bevel",
        "offset": "0,0",
        "offset_map_unit_scale": "3x:0,0,0,0,0,0",
        "offset_unit": "MM",
        "outline_color": "35,35,35,255",
        "outline_style": "solid",
        "outline_width": "0.26",
        "outline_width_unit": "MM",
        "style": "solid",
    }
]
```

How can I create a new `QgsSymbol`/`QgsFillSymbol` from this dictionary?

I can create a `QgsFillSymbol` from a list of symbol layers but I seem unable to create a `QgsSymbolLayer` from those properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a specific type of `QgsSymbolLayer`, i. e. for this case a [`QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.html):

```
properties = {
    "border_width_map_unit_scale": "3x:0,0,0,0,0,0",
    "color": "255,165,0,255",
    "joinstyle": "bevel",
    "offset": "0,0",
    "offset_map_unit_scale": "3x:0,0,0,0,0,0",
    "offset_unit": "MM",
    "outline_color": "35,35,35,255",
    "outline_style": "solid",
    "outline_width": "0.26",
    "outline_width_unit": "MM",
    "style": "solid",
}

symbol_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create(properties)
```

And then create the symbol like this:

```
symbol = QgsFillSymbol()
symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
symbol.appendSymbolLayer(symbol_layer.clone())
```

You might be tempted to use the `QgsFillSymbol(layers: Iterable[QgsSymbolLayer])` constructor but if you do, you are going to have lots of *fun* with crashes due to issues with object ownerships.